# Why am I unable to create rolling file in log4j2?

Tags: xml, log4j2

I have created a dynamic project in eclipse and trying to create logger. I wrote log4j2 code in xml file named `log4j2.xml`. That xml contains code for

1. writing into a file
2. creating a rolling file appender
3. writing in console.

My xml file is able to write in console but it is not able to perform other two function. What could be the reason?

Can any one explain me what is the difference between `root` tag and `logger` tag
 - when to add `AppenderRef ref` tag under `root` tag and when to add under `logger` tag?

My xml code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="A1" fileName="c:/Workouts/logs.log" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n" />
        </File>

        <RollingFile name="ROLLING" fileName="c:/Workouts/logsroll.log"
            filePattern="c:/Workouts/logsroll-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c: %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="0.001 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
        </RollingFile>

    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
            <AppenderRef ref="ROLLING" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="com.test.logforjtwo" level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="A1" />
        </Logger>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**java code:** class:Log4j2Example

```
package com.test.logforjtwo;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Log4j2Example {
    static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Log4j2Example.class.getName());
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.trace("Entering Log4j Example.");
        Hello hello = new Hello();
        if (!hello.callMe()) {
            logger.error("Ohh!Failed!");
        }
        logger.trace("Exiting Log4j Example.");
    }
}
```

**code** class:`Hello`

```
package com.test.logforjtwo;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Hello {
  static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Hello.class.getName());

  public boolean callMe() {
    logger.entry();
    logger.error("Inside Hello Logger!");
    logger.fatal("Inside Hello Logger 2!");
    return logger.exit(false);
  }
}
```

**output in console**

```
18:19:08.282 [main] ERROR com.test.logforjtwo.Hello - Inside Hello Logger!
18:19:08.283 [main] FATAL com.test.logforjtwo.Hello - Inside Hello Logger 2!
18:19:08.283 [main] ERROR com.test.logforjtwo.Log4j2Example - Ohh!Failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

Loggers are organised in a hierarchy.  Logger "A" is a parent of logger "A.B".  The Root logger is at the top of the hierarchy, it is the parent of "A".  In your case, Root is the parent of "com.test.logforjtwo".

The Root logger configuration is used to configure how you want logging to happen by default.
Specific "Logger" configurations like "com.test.logforjtwo" are used when you want special behaviour (different to the root configuration).

In your example, all TRACE (and DEBUG,INFO...) logs using the "com.test.logforjtwo" Logger will be logged to A1,ROLLING and CONSOLE. If you want it to only go to A1, you should use `additivity=false` on the Logger.
Other classes will send (ERROR, FATAL...) logs only to CONSOLE and ROLLING appenders.

**UPDATE**
You are using a TimeBased rollover policy, but the filePattern doesn't contain a date converter key `%d`.  I actually get an error when I use your config:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pattern does not contain a date`

So the RollingFile won't be working yet. If you change the filePattern to something valid like `/tmp/Workouts/logsroll-%d-%i.log`, then things start working.

As expected, all logs go to all appenders.  All your loglines are caught by `com.test.logforjtwo` logger, because

1. The logger catches all logs of `TRACE`-level and less verbose.
2. All your classes are in the `com.test.logforjtwo` package, such as `com.test.logforjtwo.Hello` which means the nearest logger parent in their hierarchy is `com.test.logforjtwo`.

So everything gets logged by `A1` appender, to the File.  Then, because `additivity=true` by default for loggers, the log gets passed to the `RootLogger` which logs it with `ROLLING` and `CONSOLE`.  If you want to see a different result, try changing `additivity` like:

`<Logger name="com.test.logforjtwo" level="TRACE" additivity="false">`

Then you'll see only `A1` being used, because the logger no longer passes logs to Root Logger. If you move `Hello` to another package like `com.test.other_package`, it will not be in the `com.test.logforjtwo` hierarchy, so it will log directly to its nearest ancestor, the Root Logger.

I think that initially, because there was an error in your config (no date in the filePattern), you were only seeing default logger configuration.

Comment: i am getting the desired output in console.But i want same output in a separate file for that i am using `<File>` as well as `<RollingFile>`  under `<Appenders>` tag but `<File>` and  `<RollingFile>` is not working for me.

Comment: What does your java code look like?  It would be easier to diagnose with a sample of that. Specifically, the package+class names, how you retrieve the Logger object and how you're using the logger.

Answer (score 0):

I face similar issue using TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy in xml. Removing this ttag worked for me.